# Multiple python versions with anaconda and travis

Tags: python, anaconda, travis-ci

I have a python project that makes use of libraries that needs to be built. Given that I use anaconda. I want to create a plan for travis that would let me test against multiple python versions and I am not able to do it. Here is what I have:

- I want to test it against multiple python versions (e.g. 2.7, 3.5, 3.6)
- I have `requirements.yml` file which looks like following:

> ```
>   channels:
>        - kne 
>   dependencies:
>        - numpy
>        - pytest
>        - numpy
>        - scipy
>        - matplotlib
>        - seaborn
>        - pybox2d
>        - pip:
>         - gym
>         - codecov
>         - pytest
>         - pytest-cov
> ```

My `.travis.yml` contains:

```
language: python

# sudo false implies containerized builds
sudo: false

python:
  - 3.5
  - 3.4

before_install:
# Here we download miniconda and install the dependencies
- export MINICONDA=$HOME/miniconda
- export PATH="$MINICONDA/bin:$PATH"
- hash -r
- wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
- bash miniconda.sh -b -f -p $MINICONDA
- conda config --set always_yes yes
- conda update conda
- conda info -a
- echo "Python version var"
- echo $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION
- conda env create -n testenv -f environment.yml python=$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION
- source activate testenv

install:
- python setup.py install

script:
- python --version
- python -m pytest --cov=.
- codecov
```

If I put python version into `environment.yml` it works fine but I can't use multiple python versions. For me, it seems to if `-f` is provided, it ignores any additional packages listed for `conda env create`.

Also, adding `- conda install -n testenv python=$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION` after env creation does not work.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - functools32 -> python 2.7.*
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What am I supposed to do, in order make it work?

// If you would like to see more details, it is available here: https://travis-ci.org/mbednarski/Chiron/jobs/220644726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to modify the python dependency in environment.yml file before creating the conda environment.

Include python in the environment.yml:

```
channels:
    - kne 
dependencies:
    - python=3.6
    - numpy
    - pytest
    - numpy
    - scipy
    - matplotlib
    - seaborn
    - pybox2d
    - pip:
        - gym
        - codecov
        - pytest
        - pytest-cov
```

And then modify your .travis.yml:

```
before_install:
    # Here we download miniconda and install the dependencies
    - export MINICONDA=$HOME/miniconda
    - export PATH="$MINICONDA/bin:$PATH"
    - hash -r
    - wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
    - bash miniconda.sh -b -f -p $MINICONDA
    - conda config --set always_yes yes
    - conda update conda
    - conda info -a
    - echo "Python version var"
    - echo $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION
    # Edit the environment.yml file for the target Python version
    - sed -i -E 's/(python=)(.*)/\1'$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION'/' ./environment.yml
    - conda env create -n testenv -f environment.yml
    - source activate testenv
```

The `sed` regex will replace the text python=3.6 with the equivalent for the target python version.

**BTW:** I see in your repository you've worked around this by using multiple environment.yml files. This seems reasonable, even necessary for certain dependencies, but perhaps tedious to maintain for many Python versions.